# Multiplicity of zeros and poles of a multivariable rational function

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a multivariable rational function in $\mathbb{Q}(X,Y)$, say $\frac{f(X,Y)}{g(X,Y)} $, is there a way to find out the multiplicity of zeros or poles of the function?
I may want to transform the function into a one variable function by considering it as a function over the complex plane, and $(X,Y) $ corresponds to the real part and the imaginary part. The problem is, the function of one variable I get may not be a rational function. 
In fact, I am not sure whether there exists something like multiplicity of zeros for a multivariable polynomial. But is there any similar concept for a multivariable rational function corresponding to multiplicity of zeros and poles of a one-variable rational function?

Comment: What would be your idea for the function $X/Y$ at the origin?

Comment: I don't know. I just put my guess there, but I don't know how to continue. Maybe it is wrong.